# Error module build failed, parse error with UglifyJsPlugin in webpack

Tags: docker, webpack

I'm having an error I can't find a solution to.

I have a new VueJS project that I'm running in docker. It works fine in dev mode, but fails when I try to build for prod. The error is included below, and seems to be with `eslint`. I've removed sections until it works, and narrowed it down to the `UglifyJsPlugin`, but I don't know why.

I know I can remove the Uglify process, but I don't want to -- I want to solve the problem!

Errors look like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-html-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./~/eslint-loader!./src/components/UserInput.vue
Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: <input class="form-control" type:"text" v-model="newTodoText" v-on:keyup.enter="createTodo" placeholder="New todo">
    <span class="btn btn-primary input-group-addon" v-on:click="createTodo">
    Add
    </span>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="showClearModal">
    Clear all
    </button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="clearModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            Are you sure you want do delete them all?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This will permanently destroy all todos, do you really want to do this?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" v-on:click="clearTodos">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div> 
    at new HTMLParser (/code/node_modules/html-minifier/src/htmlparser.js:236:13)
    at minify (/code/node_modules/html-minifier/src/htmlminifier.js:945:3)
    at Object.exports.minify (/code/node_modules/html-minifier/src/htmlminifier.js:1294:10)
    at Object.module.exports (/code/node_modules/vue-html-loader/index.js:85:26)
@ ./src/components/UserInput.vue 4:19-173
```

My webpack config looks like this for BASE:

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var cssLoaders = require('./css-loaders')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: config.build.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: path.join(config.build.assetsSubDirectory, '[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: cssLoaders()
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      Tether: 'tether'
    })
  ],
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  }
}
```

and PROD

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var cssLoaders = require('./css-loaders')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: path.join(config.build.assetsSubDirectory, '[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: path.join(config.build.assetsSubDirectory, '[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: cssLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
        API_HOST: JSON.stringify(config.prod.api_host)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join(config.build.assetsSubDirectory, '[name].[contenthash].css')),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: You are missing an opening `<div>` at the beginning, aren't you?

Comment: Also, in your `input` there's a typo.. it should be `type="text"`

Comment: You're totally right about the type="text", but that isn't causing the issue, as builds are working for dev.

Comment: And the missing <div> is there in the code, just not in the error message.